# Limit the user from typing numbers and characters in the first character of input field in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is what I have so far. I'm trying to limit the first character to only be letters, so replace the first character with letters.

```
const validateMyField = (currentFieldValue, event) => {
    if (currentFieldValue.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$/)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
const templateNameValidator = createValidator(
    validateMyField,
    'You are attempting to paste with characters that are not allowed. Please remove characters and try again. (Special characters can only include "_","-",".")'
);
```

```
<Field
     className="text-input"
     component={Textarea}
     label="Template Name"
     name="name"
     maxLength={128}
     minRows={1}
     placeholder="Enter Template Name..."
     validate={composeValidators(required, templateNameValidator)}
 normalize={format}/>
    export default reduxForm({
    form: 'templateForm',
    destroyOnUnmount: false,
    validate: generateValidation({
        name: templateNameValidator
    })
```

Comment: As a note in your validateField function, you do not need the if statement, you can return the expression in the if statement, and it will have the same effect, likely being more clear

Answer (score 0):

You can have an onChange function in your field that will allow functional control of your input.

*Adding information on controlling input value*

```
<Field
 className="text-input"
 component={Textarea}
 label="Template Name"
 name="name"
 maxLength={128}
 minRows={1}
 placeholder="Enter Template Name..."
 validate={composeValidators(required, 
 templateNameValidator)}
 normalize={format}

 value={this.inputValue}
 onChange={this.noNumberFirst}
/>
```

At the bottom there I added the onChange function

Your class would contain a property like:

```
 inputValue = ""
```

Then the onChange function could be something like....

```
const noNumberFirst = event => {
  const input = event.target.value
  const pattern = new RegExp("/^[a-zA-Z]/")
  if (!pattern.test(input[0])) {
    // Here you have a bad test on your element and you can alert the user
  } else {
    // This means they have passed in an acceptable value and can continue 
    // moving on with their input
   this.inputValue = e.target.value
  }
```

I chose to show you this method because it is very straightforward and should be clear to understand

Comment: Hi Benjamin! 
Would I return input in the else statement?

Comment: Best practice would be to have a property in the component like inputValue that you set to equal the acceptable inputs. Then the Field value prop would be set to the class value. No return needed.